# Display images in GridView with Glide

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

How can I use Glide image loading with GridView? I have Card class with image URL, name and description. I want to display it in GridView. In documentation is writte:

```
Glide.with(fragment)
    .load(myUrl)
    .into(imageView);
```

But how can I define here imageView if I don't know actually how many image views I'm going to have?

Below is my layout and Fragment class.

fragment_collection.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.ui.collection.CollectionFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:orientation = "vertical">
        <GridView
            android:id = "@+id/grid_cards"
            android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android:layout_height = "match_parent"
            android:columnWidth="120dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:divider = "#000"
            android:dividerHeight = "1dp"
            android:footerDividersEnabled = "false"
            android:headerDividersEnabled = "false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/android_list_view_tutorial_with_example"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="7dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_card"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="7dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_card_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_card_short_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

CollectionFragment.kt

```
class CollectionFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var collectionViewModel: CollectionViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        collectionViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(CollectionViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_collection, container, false)

        var imageCard = mutableListOf<String>()
        var cardName = mutableListOf<String>()
        var cardShortDescription = mutableListOf<String>()
        collectionViewModel.getCards().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            for (card in it) {
                imageCard.add(card.url)
                cardName.add(card.name)
                cardShortDescription.add(card.description)
            }
        })

        val images: MutableList<HashMap<String, String?>> = ArrayList()

        for (i in 0..7) {
            val map = HashMap<String, String?>()
            map["image_card"] = imageCard[i].toString()
            map["text_card_name"] = cardName[i]
            map["text_card_short_description"] = cardShortDescription[i]
            images.add(map)
        }

        val from = arrayOf("image_card", "text_card_name", "text_card_short_description")
        val to = intArrayOf(
            R.id.image_card,
            R.id.text_card_name,
            R.id.text_card_short_description
        )

        val simpleAdapter =
            SimpleAdapter(this.context, images, R.layout.fragment_card, from, to)
        val androidListView: GridView = root.findViewById(R.id.grid_cards) as GridView
        androidListView.adapter = simpleAdapter
        return root
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by  "I don't know how many images I am going to have"?

Comment: I mean that I don't know how many elements of Card I'm going to have. I don't know how to determine what to pass into to Glide.

Comment: Let me see if I get this. Your fragment_collection is the layout of your fragment, inside that fragment you want GRID elements which will be defined with fragment_card layout and added to GridView? And you are using SimpleAdapter to show your data? If that's the case, then inside your Adapter you need to glide your images. If that's not your custom adapter then create one. Then just use Glide(context).load(url).into(R.id.image_card). Depends on the adapter and overridden function, but usually, it's named "getView" or "onBindView" and that will be called for each item in your array/list of data

Comment: Here are few tutorials on how to create adapter for GridView: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gridview-using-custom-arrayadapter-in-android-with-example/ -------- https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/android/grid_view_custom_adapter.html

Comment: Thanks, custom adapter looks like the solution to my problem! Second link explains the whole concept very well.

Comment: I am glad I could help, happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone would look for example of the Adapter which passes image and some textes into GridView with usage of Glide here is what I have came up basing on the tutorial from this link https://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/android/grid_view_custom_adapter.html .

```
class CardAdapter constructor(private val context: Context, private val images: MutableList<HashMap<String, String?>>) :  BaseAdapter() {

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return images.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return images[position]
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        var view = convertView

        if(view == null) {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card, parent, false)
        }

        val card = view!!.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image_card)
        val name : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.text_card_name)
        val description : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.text_card_short_description)

        Glide.with(context)
            .load(images[position]["image_card"])
            .into(card)

        name.text = images[position]["text_card_name"]
        description.text = images[position]["text_card_short_description"]

        return view
    }

}
```